# Setting classpath and installing database via batch file

Tags: java, windows, classpath

I want my classpath to be set via a batch file. I'm working on **Windows XP**.
I have **two questions:**
**My first question:**

I made a batch file in which 
I typed
`"set classpath = C:\WINDOWS\system32\;.;C:\jdk1.5.0\lib\tools.jar;C:\poi-3.6\poi-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\poi-3.6\poi-contrib-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\poi-3.6\poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\poi-3.6\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\poi-3.6\poi-scratchpad-3.6-20091214.jar;E:\jdbc\postgresql-8.2-505.jdbc3.jar;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\resolver.jar;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\xbean.jar;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\xbean_xpath.jar;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\xmlbeans-qname.jar;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\xmlpublic.jar;C:\dom4j-1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;

exit"`  
     When I tried to run this file it ran but when I went into control panel >system>advanced>environment variables and then selected classpath, it didn't show me the classpath I did set. What is the correct way to set the classpath via batch file?

**My second question:**

Is there any way by which we can install database via batch file say for eg: postgresql8.2?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have two questions, then post two questions.

Comment: you could use a light java database (like hsqldb, derby, ...) which can be easily installed via batch file. for postgresql see skaffmans answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the classpath from the command line affects only that batch process, it has no effect on the classpath that will be used for new processes. I don't know how to do what you're trying to do from the command line, but it likely involves mucking about in the registry.

Comment: Thank you. But can u tell me something more about mucking into registry and how it is going to solve my problem?

Comment: @Supereme: it's not going to solve your problem; most likely it will create more problems.

Answer (score 0):

go to the control panel of windos environment variables set the class path there it self, it is the best way and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

The global classpath environment variable should not be set *at all*. It's an antiquated concept from the earliest days of Java that has unfortunately survived via outdated internet tutorials and textbooks.

The classpath should be set for each application individually, preferably [via the command line](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) when starting the application.